# JUnit - test that a method has been called

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm new to unit testing, and I'm trying to test that a method has been called. The method in question doesn't return anything.

```
public void example (boolean foo) {

    if (foo) {
        processFoo(foo);
    } 
    else if (foo==false) {
        processSomethingElse(foo);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to test that the `processFoo` method is being called, but I don't know how to do that.

If mocking is required, then I have to use `JMockit`. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing and assert case for void method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230150/unit-testing-and-assert-case-for-void-method)

Comment: You can create `spy` of a class under the test throwing some exception when `processFoo` method is being called. If you catch this exception, everything is ok, otherwise this method hadn't been called.

Comment: Side note: `foo` can only be true or false. So your code should be `if (foo) {..} else {...}`.

Comment: Duncan, I know, this doesn't exactly match the code I'm using (which is for work so I can't directly copy and paste) it's actually not a boolean, but this seemed like the easiest way to explain the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm a little late to the party, but I have a couple of ideas for you.

First, you mention that one option is to use JMockit--that's great as it gives you a lot of flexibility. If you use JMockit, then the visibility of your processFoo() method doesn't much matter. Let's see what that might look like:

```
public class Subject {

    public void example (boolean foo) {
        if (foo) {
            processFoo(foo);
        }
        else if (foo==false) {
            processSomethingElse(foo);
        }
    }

    private void processFoo(boolean b) {
        System.out.println("b = " + b);
    }

    private void processSomethingElse(boolean bb) {
        System.out.println("bb = " + bb);
    }

}
```

So, one caveat with this option, though is that I'm going to assume processFoo() is a method on your test subject and I'm going to use a partial mock to change the test subject--not something I really like to do, but this is an example. In general, it is best to only mock the dependencies of your test subject rather than behavior of the test subject itself--you have been advised! Note that the processFoo() method of the test subject is private. I'm going to substitute a method for the test with JMockit's partial mocking and the visibility of that new method does not have to match the original.

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import mockit.Mock;
import mockit.MockUp;
import mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SubjectTest {

    private Subject testSubject = new Subject();
    private boolean processFooCalled = false;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        new MockUp<Subject>() {
            @Mock
            public void processFoo(boolean b) {
                processFooCalled = true;
            };
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void should_call_processFoo() {
        testSubject.example(true);
        assertThat(processFooCalled).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_not_call_processFoo() {
        testSubject.example(false);
        assertThat(processFooCalled).isFalse();
    }

}
```

Ok, so that was the first option. It's actually a little easier if you forget JMockit for this one, assuming you are able to subclass your test subject and override the processFoo() method:

```
public class Subject {

    public void example (boolean foo) {
        if (foo) {
            processFoo(foo);
        }
        else if (foo==false) {
            processSomethingElse(foo);
        }
    }

    protected void processFoo(boolean b) {    // NOTE: protected access here!
        System.out.println("b = " + b);
    }

    private void processSomethingElse(boolean bb) {
        System.out.println("bb = " + bb);
    }

}
```

So, in this case, the strategy is simply to subclass your test subject and replace the implementation of the method you wish to observe being called. It might look like this:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SubjectTest2 {

    private Subject testSubject = new TestableSubject();
    private boolean processFooCalled = false;

    @Test
    public void should_call_processFoo() {
        testSubject.example(true);
        assertThat(processFooCalled).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_not_call_processFoo() {
        testSubject.example(false);
        assertThat(processFooCalled).isFalse();
    }

    class TestableSubject extends Subject {
        @Override
        protected void processFoo(boolean b) {
            processFooCalled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Give it a whirl. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter variable in your class and increment it whenever the method is called, or use a print statement. If you don't have access to the `processFoo` method, a simple approach would be to do this at the time that `processFoo` is called in another method, **if that's the only place where it can possibly be called**.

For example:

```
public static int processFooCalls = 0;
// ...
public void example (boolean foo) {
    if (foo) {
        processFoo(foo);
        processFooCalls += 1;
        // and/or
        System.out.println("processFoo method was called");
    }
    // ...
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    // main routine here...
    System.out.println("'processFoo' was called " + processFooCalls + " times.");
}
```

If `processFoo` can be called elsewhere, and you need to consider this possibility as well, then you'll need to have access to the `processFoo` code in order to do this, e.g.:

```
void processFoo( boolean b ) {

    // increment number of times processFoo was called here, and/or print, as follows
    processFooCalls += 1;
    System.out.println("called processFoo method!");

    /* some functionality */
}
```

Comment: Instrumenting code solely for testing is a smell; there are any number of mocking frameworks designed specifically to test behavior like "was this called", "ensure it was called n times [with argument x]" etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton based on the fact that OP mentioned `JMockit`, I think your comment is applicable and should indicate that my solution isn't ideal. I've never used a mocking framework in any depth nor did I know what a [smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) referred to. (Thanks!) tl;dr - I think my answer works for trivial / small-scale / controlled test environments, but the answer is far from being universally correct.

Comment: In addition to what @Dave said, adding a print statement for a unit test is a big no-no.  This means you have to manually check if your test passed or not

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JMockit documentation, you will need the following tools:

Static Mocking: http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#staticPartial

Invocation Counts: http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#constraints

Combining the two in a test (my syntax may be a little off since I'm more accustomed to Mockito, but the concept should hold):

```
@Test
public void someTestMethod(@Mocked({"processFoo"}) final ExampleClass exampleclass)
{
    new Expectations() {{
        exampleclass.processFoo(); times = 1;
    }};
    exampleclass.example(true);
}
```

This should mock the processFoo method, leaving everything else intact, and checks to make sure it is called exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

Don't consider doing any kind of partial mocking for this, all you're doing in that case is ensuring that if you want to refactor your code your tests will fail.  There is a mantra in unit testing - "never test private methods".

What you should be doing is testing that the method you call conforms to the behaviour you want to see.  In this case what happens when `foo` is true is what's important, not that it calls `processFoo`.  So if `foo` is true you want to be testing that the action `processFoo` carries out is true *and nothing else*.